# Where can I give a name to an assembly connector in a component diagram?

Tags: uml, components

I have a component diagram with two component instances, and an assembly connector between them. Currently, there is a label in the assembly connector where it is written: "<<cooperative perception>>". Is it ok, or should I put this text as the name of the ports ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not valid to put a assembly connector between two components. Assembly connector is a link between two instances of components and shows that they are linked thrpugh interface. Therefore, the corresponding interface name shoud be used as a label here.

If "cooperative perception" is the interface name, that this is ok.

Here is an illustration of a similar situation. It clarifyes the relationship between interfaces (on component level) and assemblies (on instance level):

[image]

Another point. <<...>> is user to indicate a stereotype in UML. You should not use it arround the interface names, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "component instances", I edited my question. Ok, but in my case, I don't want to exhibit the required/provided interfaces. So, I just use ports on both component instances, and the provided/required interfaces of both ports are described in another diagram. In [link](http://www.pst.ifi.lmu.de/~janisch/pub/Hennicker2009.pdf) (page 7), the author gives a name "ab" and a type "Bat" to the assembly connector. I think that I can do it in my case, and use "cooperative perception" as name (without << >>)

Comment: By the way, it looks like assembly connectors are also ok for components. An assembly connector is a connector between two components that defines that one component provides the services that another component requires. It is a way to avoid specifying required/provided interfaces and to do that in another diagram where ports' provided/required interfaces are listed.

Comment: I don't think assemblies are ok with components, they are kind of links. Maybe you've seen an example on a structured classifier, where it connects two parts. Parts are however kind of instances.

Comment: Actually, I found after reading that "ports" are "parts" of the components. Hence, a "port" is an instance. As a consequence, it is ok to draw (and to call it) a link between two ports of two components. When the link is directional, it means that one of the ports implements required interfaces of the other port. If bidirectional, it means that both ports implement required interfaces of the other port. Are you right with this ? Now, is it ok to call this link an assembly connector ?

Comment: Yes, I would say so, but parts (ports) are kind of instances. If this can be considered as a relationship between components, it sounds more correct. Composite structure is after all some kind of mix between class and instance diagram.